pactl return sink input for active window
I have a macropad with dials, one of which I've assigned to change the volume of the active window in Linux Mint. I've recently gone from Mint 21 to 22, so no more PulseAudio or pacmd.
My solution using pactl is not very efficient or elegant. My question here then is: what is the better way to achieve this, if there is one?
$change = 5
pulsemixer is an additional program.
vol_up() { 
    adjust_volume $change "+"; 
}

vol_down() { 
    adjust_volume $change "-"; 
}

adjust_volume() { 
    sink_list=$(get_index "$1")
    pids_count=$(echo $sink_list | awk {'print NF'})

    for (( i=1; i<=$pids_count; i++ )); do
        sink=$(echo $sink_list | awk -v col=$i {'print $col'})
        pulsemixer --id sink-input-$sink --change-volume $2$1 --max-volume 100
    done
}

function get_index() {
    
    pactl list sink-inputs | while read -r line ; do

        local testo=$(echo $line | grep -oP 'Sink Input #\K[^$]+')

        if ! [ -z "$testo" ]; then
          local sink=$testo
        else 
          local testo=$(echo $line | grep -oP 'application.process.id = "\K[^"]+')
          if ! [ -z "$testo" ]; then
            local PID=$testo
            if [ $PID = $pid ]; then
                echo $sink
            fi
          fi
        fi

    done 
}

The big cost is getting from the active window PID to the sink. This is one audio sink, there are several, and can be more than one per PID:
Sink Input #2298766
    Driver: PipeWire
    Owner Module: n/a
    Client: 2295730
    Sink: 905
    Sample Specification: float32le 6ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "48000"  format.channels = "6"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe\""
    Corked: yes
    Mute: yes
    Volume: front-left: 52429 /  80% / -5.81 dB,   front-right: 52429 /  80% / -5.81 dB,   rear-left: 52429 /  80% / -5.81 dB,   rear-right: 52429 /  80% / -5.81 dB,   front-center: 52429 /  80% / -5.81 dB,   lfe: 52429 /  80% / -5.81 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 0 usec
    Sink Latency: 0 usec
    Resample method: PipeWire
    Properties:
        client.api = "pipewire-pulse"
        pulse.server.type = "unix"
        application.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 3.0.20)"
        application.id = "org.VideoLAN.VLC"
        application.version = "3.0.20"
        application.icon_name = "vlc"
        application.language = "en_GB.UTF-8"
        application.process.id = "852456"
        application.process.user = "mint"
        application.process.host = "mint-7B98"
        application.process.binary = "vlc"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "10b971ac1a304176906b1f6a23827476"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
        media.role = "video"
        media.name = "audio stream"
        node.rate = "1/48000"
        node.latency = "1920/48000"
        stream.is-live = "true"
        node.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 3.0.20)"
        node.want-driver = "true"
        node.autoconnect = "true"
        media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio"
        adapt.follower.spa-node = ""
        object.register = "false"
        factory.id = "6"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        client.id = "108"
        object.id = "60"
        object.serial = "2298766"
        pulse.attr.maxlength = "4194288"
        pulse.attr.tlength = "138240"
        pulse.attr.prebuf = "0"
        pulse.attr.minreq = "46080"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:video"

With pacmd, I could achieve the sink in one line without the looping using awk. The above takes around 0.5s on my system so is significant.
0.5s seconds execution. I'm looking for either a better way to parse pactl list sink-inputs, or a better way to return the sink from the active window, via the PID or otherwise.
I have been able to change the volume of pipewire nodes, but this does not match the system volumes of mint and shows unexpected behaviour. I don't quite understand this, or why pulsemixer still works at all without pulseaudio. Just understanding what is going on with pipewire and pulse on Mint 22 would be valuable for me.
There is this, where I have taken some perl from for my solution. And single a single line solution using pacmd, but not pactl. I cannot comment there with a rep under 50.
